# Controlling curl output on Debian

Tags: debian, perl, curl, stdout

I'd like to run a curl command and only have content written to stdout if there is an error.

When I run the command from the terminal I get this functionality by default. When I run the command from within a perl script though (``), it outputs the progress info but not any error messages.

I'm able to hide the progress info by appending the `-s` (`--silent`) flag, but I can't force errors to be displayed the way they do when ran directly from bash. The `-S` (`--show-errors`) flag seems to have no effect.

I've also tried playing with diverting the output to /etc/null, but this seems to prevent anything from being output at all.

```
my $curl_result = `curl -s -S -X PUT "$url" -H "$h1" -H "$h2" -H "$h3"  -d  "$data"`;
```

Below is an example of the kind of error I'd like to look for. This one is caused by a purposefully malformed IP:

```
{
    "code":"INVALID_RECORDS",
    "message":"One or more of the given records is invalid",
    "fields": [{
        "code":"INVALID_RECORDS",
        "message":"Invalid [ipaddress] provided for record data, [test].",
        "path":"records"
    }],
    "name":"ApiError",
    "errors":["Invalid [ipaddress] provided for record data, [test]."]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between errors that curl sees, and errors that your http server is returning. The latter are not errors for curl. You can however easily inspect the http status code by adding to your curl the option

```
 -w '\n%{http_code}\n'
```

This will append to stdout the HTTP header, which is 200 for OK. So your perl can do something like

```
my $curl_result = `curl -s -S -w '\n%{http_code}\n' ... 2>/dev/null`;
my @lines = split(/\n/,$curl_result);
my $httpcode = $lines[-1];
if($httpcode eq 200){ print "ok\n"; }
else{ print "error\n"; }
```

Comment: That got me to my answer, thanks! I should note that the response lines weren't terminated by `\n` chars so the split line didn't do anything. `$curl_result` came back with the value `null200`. I was content though with `if(index($curl_result, "200") != -1)`.

Comment: I suppose you could use `-w '\n%{http_code}\n'` (with an extra newline at the start) to ensure there is a split.

Comment: That did the trick. I also used the `2>/dev/null` clause recommended elsewhere to get rid of any other info that we wouldn't want.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I rejected your edit by mistake. I'll put it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's backtick operator will return (to your $curl_result variable) the STDOUT of the command you run. STDERR from that command will carry through to the calling program/terminal *of* your perl script -- perhaps to your screen, as if you had called `curl` yourself.

In order to capture the STDERR, you must (as you began to imagine) drop STDOUT or commingle the two.

Here's an example of dropping STDOUT and redirecting STDERR to STDOUT so that it (instead of the "normal" STDOUT) is captured by the perl variable:

```
my $curl_result = `curl ... 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
```

Alternatively, commingle the two:

```
my $curl_result = `curl ... 2>&1`;
```

I omitted the middle of the bulk `curl` command to make it clear what part I changed. The first example changes STDERR to point instead to where STDOUT is *currently* pointing, then tells STDOUT to go away.  The second example tells STDERR to point to STDOUT, commingling the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I'd done when I'd mentioned diverting the output to `/etc/null`. When I add the appendation `2>&1 1>/dev/null` and modify the code to fail on purpose, it still does so quietly with no complaint.

Comment: Any stderr should be captured in the variable; are you checking the `$?` variable for return status?

Comment: That's my understanding, too. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. The value of `$?` seems to be `0` regardless of whether or not the server accepts the curl request.

Comment: You may have to `grep` the output for indicators of success or failure, then.

Comment: Is there a way to do that when I don't have access to the output from within the perl script? That's have I've been trying to get access to.

Comment: The redirections should gather the output for you...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76084/discussion-between-nathan-and-jeff-schaller).